# Revealing module pattern method echo undefined

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

I wrote this function as revealing module pattern, but when I call the `get` method in console by `metadataModule.get();` it echoes `undefined` in console.

```
var metadataModule = function () {
    var metadataurl = 'http://farskids326.com/data.json';

    function getMetadata() {
        console.log("Metadata Function Called")
        $.ajax({
            url: metadataurl,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return {
        get: getMetadata,
    };
}();
```

Where did I made a mistake in this code?

Comment: Is this a cross-domain request? These won't work by default with Ajax.

Comment: no,it's not cross-domain request!

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you eventually see your data logged into the console or not? Calling `metadataModule.get()` in the console, will log `undefined`, because the method does not return any value. Is `"Metadata Fucntion Called"` logged? Have a look at the network tab. Is the request properly sent? What is the response?

Answer (score 0):

When you are working in the console, the return value of the last expresion is echoed after any command. The method you are using doesn't have an explicit return value. So, that may be why you see `undefined`.

This probably means that your ajax call is encountering an error. Try changing it to log when either success or error happens, like so:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: metadataurl , 
  dataType: "json", 
  success: function(data){
    console.log('called success!');
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log('called error!');
  }
});
```

Then, when you run your code, you should see exactly which callback is being executed. Hopefully, that will give you a good starting point for debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The getMetadata function returns nothing so yes, it will output undefined. for it to respond with the content of the JSON you need to make the ajax call synchronous and return the value you get.

```
var metadataModule = function () {
   var metadataurl = 'http://farskids326.com/data.json';

   function getMetadata() {
       console.log("Metadata Function Called")
       var content = {}
       $.ajax({
           url: metadataurl,
           async : false,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (data) {
               content = data;
           }
       });
       return content
   }
   return {
       get: getMetadata,
   };
}();
```

Comment: Yes it is. But you can't have a function to return the content of a ajax call without making it synchronous. The browser will freeze a bit every time but you don't know the full context of the code. And just vaguely pointing out that something is a bad design practice/ideea is worst. Just doing it and seeing for yourself why is not such a good ideea is better. PErhaps his next question will be about callbacks :)